# convert angular js1.x filter to angular js 2.0 pipes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-filters, angular-pipe

I need to convert the angular 1.x filter to angular 2.0 pipes please help me to, below is my angular js 1.x filter code

```
$scope.selectname1={};    
    $scope.selectname2={};    
    $scope.selectname3={};

    $scope.filter1 = function(item){
      return (!($scope.selectname1&&$scope.selectname1.id)||item.id !=$scope.selectname1.id);
    };

    $scope.filter2 = function(item){
      return (!($scope.selectname2&&$scope.selectname2.id)||item.id!=$scope.selectname2.id);
    };
    $scope.filter3 = function(item){
      return (!($scope.selectname3&&$scope.selectname3.id)||item.id !=$scope.selectname3.id);
    };
```

Answer (score 1):

Create pipe class

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({name: 'filter1'})
export class ExponentialStrengthPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: number, exponent: string): number {
    return exponent; // do something with your vallue
  }
}
```

After that in your component add and include pipe

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ExponentialStrengthPipe } from './exponential-strength.pipe';

    @Component({
      selector: 'power-booster',
      template: `
        <h2>Power Booster</h2>
        <p>Super power boost: {{2 | filter1}}</p>
      `,
      pipes: [ExponentialStrengthPipe]
    })
    export class PowerBoosterComponent { }
```

Comment: this is a syntax which I know, but am stuck with that, better can you write a pipe code for only one filter for this   $scope.filter1 = function(item){
      return (!($scope.selectname1&&$scope.selectname1.id)||item.id !=$scope.selectname1.id);
    };